# Node.js require library that cannot find the module

Tags: node.js

When I use the require function, I cannot get the module and has the error like this:

When I use require("strip-bom"), it has the error:

```
System.Exception: Error: Cannot find module 'strip-bom'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at eval (eval at compileFunc 
(C:\dev\Work\dm\edi.pbl\edge\double_edge.js:34:23), <anonymous>:35:19)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotificati on(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at DotNetCom.EdgeJsCom.<RunJs>d__0.MoveNext()
```

But I require("../common_js/node_modules/strip-bom"), 
it can find the module,

My question is how the use require("strip-bom") to find module instead of use path to require the module?

Comment: Is `strip-bom` in your package.json and installed locally?

Comment: I find my package.json has strip-bom and installed locally using npm install.
Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "common_js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "base64toimg.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "alasql": "^0.4.6",
    "base64-img": "^1.0.4",
    "clean-deep": "^3.0.2",
    "csvtojson": "^1.1.12",
    "json2csv": "^3.11.5",
    "replaceall": "^0.1.6",
    "strip-bom": "^3.0.0"
  }
}

Comment: require looks in `node_modules`. It seems that you've changed your project structure to something not supported; otherwise it wouldn't be found in `common_js`.

Comment: how to I fixed this problem. Because when I reinstall the node.js, It also has this problem

Comment: Don't change your project structure to something unsupported... Don't place node_modules in a folder, but in the project's root

Comment: it solves the problem, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not installed the package in your project's directory.

Try `npm install strip-bom`
This will install the package in the `node_modules` directory of your project.

What you tried `require("../common_js/node_modules/strip-bom")` is other module's `node_modules` directory.